# Try isn't catching my error from an async/await function in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, babeljs

```
       try {
            const user = await User.create({
                username,
                password: hash,
                email,
            });
            return res.json({
                status: 'success',
                object: {
                    username: user.username,
                    email: user.email,
                },
            });
        } catch (error2) {
            return res.status(500).send('Username already in use');
        }
```

I'm testing to make sure you can't add the same two usernames to the database, and you can't it throws an error, but the error isnt being caught and the client never gets any type of response from the server after it makes the request. does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error handling in asynchronous node.js calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816436/error-handling-in-asynchronous-node-js-calls)

Comment: How are you calling this async function?

Comment: My guess is that there's an additional error being thrown inside your `catch` handler (does `res` exist?), which will get swallowed if you don't also handle it.

Comment: When an exception is thrown from an `async` method, it is used to complete the promise returned from that method. It's not raised directly.